# image processing why Gaussian smoothing is commonly used with edge detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Why is Gaussian smoothing commonly used with edge detection?

What is the most suitable smoothing method for an edge detection algorithm? Is it Gaussian smoothing? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Gaussian smoothing is commonly used with edge detection because we are not here to do your homework, please ask questions about what specific problems you have run into, providing information about what you have tried.

Comment: thank you junuxx.... just i want to know that think thats why i ask

Answer (score 5):

A simple google with your own question header would've answered your question.

Basically to avoid noise affecting detection.

"Because these kernels are approximating a second derivative measurement on the image, they are very sensitive to noise. To counter this, the image is often Gaussian smoothed before applying the Laplacian filter."

from .. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm